# how to make font bold,unbold of any font style

Tags: ios, uifont

Can anybody please explain how can we make any font family font, bold or unbold + Italic or Non Italic + Underlined or Non underLined. Everywhere I got the method that make the changes but on system font. I even tried giving 2 attributes to NSAttributed string
 1. Bold
 2. A font family from list of supported font family

But it didnt work. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: A list of fonts (including variations) and their corresponding names http://iosfonts.com

Comment: Underline can be done by NSAttributed String,but how about combination of bold/unbold and italic/non italic

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [[UIFontDescriptor alloc] init];

UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptorForHelveticaNeue = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFamily:@"Helvetica Neue"];

UIFontDescriptor *symbolicFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptorForHelveticaNeue fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];

UIFontDescriptor *symbolicFontDescriptor1 = [fontDescriptorForHelveticaNeue fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitMonoSpace];

NSString *text = @"iOS 7";

if(some condition){

    CGSize fontSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:symbolicFontDescriptor size:17.0f]}];
}
else{
    CGSize fontSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:symbolicFontDescriptor1 size:17.0f]}];
}
```

Comment: I was trying this solution,but I could not import "UIFontDescriptor.h",even after including Core Text Framework.

Comment: You do not need to import this file, i tried without importing and it worked for me.

Comment: Above code errors out in my m/c says UIFontDescriptor not declared even after including the CoreText Framework

Comment: UIFontDescriptor is available from iOS 7 onwards, please check if you supporting earlier version?

Comment: You still need to check you're building for iOS7 (and up) in Xcode 5 for the library to be available ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a few lines of code. A normal font and its bold version are completely separated (ie they're like two unrelated fonts), and if you have a look at [iosfonts](http://iosfonts.com/), the naming is not consistent. Some fonts don't have bold version, and some have several bold versions!

A solution (that requires a bit of effort, but surely works): create a list of pairs of font names, like this

```
{"ArialHebrew", "ArialHebrew-Bold"},
{"AvenirNext-Regular", "AvenirNext-Bold"},
...
```

And populate the list of fonts with the regular version (the left one). If the user desires to make it bold, then switch to the bold version (the right one).

My recommendation is to limit the number of choices for user (as iOS always does): you don't need to copy the whole list from iosfonts! just some popular ones are enough.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be sufficiently generic for your purses, but maybe it'll help someone else

```
+ (UIFont *)whateverInvertedBoldnessFontFromFont:(UIFont *)font pointSize:(CGFloat)pointSize
{
    NSString *customFontFamilyName = @"Whatever";
    NSString *ibFontName = font.fontName;
    NSString *customFontStyle = nil;

    if ([ibFontName rangeOfString:@"Bold"].location != NSNotFound) {
        customFontStyle = @"Regular";
    }
    else {
        customFontStyle = @"Bold";
    }

    UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", customFontFamilyName, customFontStyle] size:pointSize];
    return customFont;
}
```

unfortunately this is quite fragile and works reliably when the source and destination
font families are known

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it programmatically, you must check with the font supported by xCode (iOS).
and if you want to do bold to any font then you have to  use :

```
 UIFont* boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
 [myLabel setFont:boldFont];
```

where myLabel is your label name.

Comment: it always gives system font. I need to apply bold,unbold on any font family(supported by apple) selected by the user.